# Drag a CGRect using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, drag, uipangesturerecognizer, cgrect

I am subclassing `UIView`, and am trying to "drag" a `CGRect` back and forth across the screen. Basically I want to move(redraw) the rectangle every time I drag my finger. So far, I have this code:

```
var rectangle: CGRect {
    get {
        return CGRect(x: 200,
                    y: 200,
                    width: frame.width / 6,
                    height: 15)
    }

    set {}
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragRectangle(recognizer:)))
    addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    drawRectangle(rect)
}

func drawRectangle(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rectangle)
    UIColor.black.set()
    path.fill()
}

@objc func dragRectangle(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self)
    rectangle = CGRect(x: rectangle.midX + translation.x, y: rectangle.midY + translation.y, width: rectangle.width, height: rectangle.height)
    setNeedsDisplay()
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
}
```

This is my first time using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, so I'm not sure of all the details that go into this. I have set breakpoints in `drawRectangle` and confirmed that this is being called. However, the rectangle on the screen does not move at all, no matter how many times I try to drag it. What's wrong?

Comment: Don't add UIPanGestureRecognizer in `draw` method, add it into init method. Or the gesture will be added multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (check comments through code):

```
@IBDesignable
class Rectangle: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet { backgroundColor = color }
    }
    // draw your view using the background color
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundColor?.set()
        UIBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()
    }
    // add the gesture recognizer to your view
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan)))
    }
    // your gesture selector
    @objc func pan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        //  update your view frame origin
        frame.origin += gesture.translation(in: self)  
        // reset the gesture translation
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension CGPoint {
    static func +=(lhs: inout CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) {
        lhs.x += rhs.x
        lhs.y += rhs.y
    }
}
```

---

To draw rectangles on your view when panning you can do as follow:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var rectangles: [Rectangle] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan)))
    }
    @objc func pan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            let rectangle = Rectangle(frame: .init(origin: gesture.location(in: view), size: .init(width: 0, height: 0)))
            rectangle.fillColor = .red
            rectangle.strokeColor = .white
            rectangle.lineWidth = 3
            view.addSubview(rectangle)
            rectangles.append(rectangle)
        case .changed:
            let distance = gesture.translation(in: view)
            let index = rectangles.index(before: rectangles.endIndex)
            let frame = rectangles[index].frame
            rectangles[index].frame = .init(origin: frame.origin, size: .init(width: frame.width + distance.x, height: frame.height + distance.y))
            rectangles[index].setNeedsDisplay()
            gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
        case .ended:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48mklm2t1jyo1x3/Draggable%20Rectangle.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am very close to making this work(see my own answer), but I still need a bit of help making the rectangle "animate".

Comment: I think it should be relatively simple to make it work in a UIView subclass instead of a controller. You can use the sample project above  as a starting point. If you run into trouble let me know

Answer (score 2):

> **This is how you can do it easily. just copy paste and run this.**

```
//
//  RootController.swift
//  SampleApp
//
//  Created by Chanaka Caldera on 24/6/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 homeapps. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class RootController: UIViewController {

    private var draggableView: UIView!
    private var pangesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setdragview()

    }
}

extension RootController {
    fileprivate func setdragview() {
        draggableView = UIView()
        draggableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        draggableView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        view.addSubview(draggableView)

        let draggableviewConstraints = [draggableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 10),
                                        draggableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64),
                                        draggableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                                        draggableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(draggableviewConstraints)

        pangesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        draggableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        draggableView.addGestureRecognizer(pangesture)
        pangesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(draggableFunction(_:)))

    }
}

extension RootController {
    @objc fileprivate func draggableFunction(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggableView)
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        draggableView.center = CGPoint(x: draggableView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggableView.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        print("drag works : \(translation.x)")
    }
}
```

here is the demo,

[image]

Hope this will help. cheers !

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. However, I would like to perform custom drawing in my subclass of `UIView`. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: @Xcoder check the updated answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729268/2303865 and sample project where you can draw and drag as well https://www.dropbox.com/s/48mklm2t1jyo1x3/Draggable%20Rectangle.zip?dl=1

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks so much, but what would I do if I want to code in a subclass of `UIView`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am very close to making this work(see my own answer), but I still need a bit of help making the rectangle "animate".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out most of the problem as to why the rectangle wasn't moving. It turns out that I misunderstood how variable getters and setters work in Swift. Nevertheless, I changed this code:

```
var rectangle: CGRect {
    get {
        return CGRect(x: 200,
                    y: 200,
                    width: frame.width / 6,
                    height: 15)
    }

    set {}
}
```

to be a `lazy` variable:

```
lazy var rectangle: CGRect = {
    return CGRect(x: 200,
                         y: 200,
                         width: self.frame.width / 6,
                         height: 15)
}()
```

The reason I needed `get` and `set` in the first place was because I use `frame` in my variable calculations, and that was not available until the view itself was fully instantiated. I also tweaked this code a bit:

```
rectangle = CGRect(x: rectangle.midX + translation.x, y: rectangle.midY + translation.y, width: rectangle.width, height: rectangle.height)
```

and used `minX` instead of `midX`:

```
rectangle = CGRect(x: rectangle.minX + translation.x, y: rectangle.minY + translation.y, width: rectangle.width, height: rectangle.height)
```

This is because `CGRect` is initialized with the x and y parameters being the `minX` and `minY`.

This is good progress(at least the rectangle moves). However, I am not able to figure out why the rectangle only switches places after I have released my mouse, resulting in choppy movement.