# how to move a object not transforming

Tags: swift, constraints, transform, uipangesturerecognizer

I want my swift code to move the object pic. I was told by someone that my code is not actually moving the object its only transforming the object. If I just use pan gesture does it actually move the object or what other code do i need to add? I dont have prior experience with this before and it is new to me.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mover = UIPanGestureRecognizer()    
    var greenTransition: CGAffineTransform?
    var jake = true
    var pic = UIView()
    var g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        [pic].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        pic.backgroundColor = .red
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.5),
            pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor,multiplier: 0.5),
        ])
        g2 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.g1Method))
        pic.addGestureRecognizer(g2)
    }
    @objc func g1Method(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if jake == true {
            guard let child = sender.view else{return}
            let transitionPoint = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            let newTransition = CGAffineTransform(translationX: transitionPoint.x, y: transitionPoint.y)
            switch sender.state {
            case .ended,.cancelled:// on End
                if let existing = greenTransition {
                    greenTransition = newTransition.concatenating(existing)
                } else {
                    greenTransition = newTransition
                }
            default://on change and other states
                if let existing = greenTransition {
                    child.transform = newTransition
                        .concatenating(existing)
                } else {
                    child.transform = newTransition
                }
                
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a CABasicAnimation and simply change its position

Comment: If you really want to change the UIView position you better animate its constraints instead of applying a transform to the view

Comment: @LeoDabus can you code a example of that

Comment: Take a look at this post. It shows how to create draggable views https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729268/2303865